# функция findShort(s)

Tags: javascript

Дается строка из слов. Нужна длина самого короткого слова. Исключено, что строка пустая или она не является ей.
Вот накидал:

```
function findShort(s) {
    var words = s.split(" ");
    var lengthOfMin = words[0].length;
    for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length > lengthOfMin) {
            lengthOfMin = words[i].length;
        }
    }
    return lengthOfMin;
}
```

Выкидывает ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку???

Comment: Неверное значение

Comment: При каком параметре?

Comment: Конечно же строка из слов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это потому, что вы ищете не минимальное, а максимальное слово. Замените

```
if (words[i].length > lengthOfMin) {
```

на

```
if (words[i].length < lengthOfMin) {
```

и все будет работать

Comment: Как же я не заметил! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

**самого короткого**

```
if (words[i].length < lengthOfMin) {
```